# Exporting dataframe to existing Excel sheet in workbook breaks pivot slicer connection in other sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

My code works exactly like I would like it to by taking the data from the df and inserting it into the desired Excel file while skipping the appropriate rows. However, when I hit the .save() function other sheets that reference the data (mostly through pivots) seem to break even though they were not touched by the writer. I can insert the data into another Excel file, copy, and paste the exact same data where the python data puts it and the corresponding sheets do not break, but display the correct information. How do you stop other sheets from breaking when Python write to the file?

```
filename_in = 'File Location In'
filename_out = 'File Location Out'
sheet_name = 'Detail'
pos_detail_data_df.to_excel(filename_in, sheet_name=sheet_name, header = False, index = False)
df = pd.read_excel(filename_in, sheet_name=sheet_name)
book = load_workbook(filename_in)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename_out, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
writer.sheets
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False, startrow = 2, header = False)
writer.save()
```

Edit:
The code was updated to reflect the assistance from below. However, now the process will simply remove everything from my filename_out and replace it with only the sheets from filename_in

Comment: where is `df` used?  It's created but then `pos_detail_data_df.to_excel(writer` appears. what does "seem to break" mean?

Comment: @MDR I'm still relatively new to Python and that was just included in the original coding I was working with. By "break" I mean when I insert the data the first sheet (which is not being written to) no longer maintains its slicers, or "repeat item" in the field setting.

Comment: The code looks incomplete. If you adjust worksheets that are referred elsewhere in the workbook, you'll have to update the references yourself.

Comment: @CharlieClark FYI: commented on my answer that it's a slicer extension.  I believe they are unsupported as per https://groups.google.com/g/openpyxl-users/c/TKnnFMISB0c from Oct 2020.

Comment: I don't think slicers are relevant to any breakages. Openpyxl will simply remove them but that, of itself, shouldn't break anything as per the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found an Excel file with a slicer so I took a look.

**Sample file:**

- Site: https://www.contextures.com/excelpivottableslicers.html#download

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# sample Excel file with slicers.
# if required download and unzip and put in the folder with this script
sample_file = 'https://www.contextures.com/pivotsamples/regionsalesslicer.zip'

# set your filename_in, filename_out, and sheet_name
filename_in = 'regionsalesslicer.xlsx'
filename_out = 'regionsalesslicerUpdated.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sales Data'

# read in the Excel file with pd.read_excel rather than pd.ExcelFile
# just to play safe and avoid any BadZipFile: File is not a zip file errors
df = pd.read_excel(filename_in, sheet_name=sheet_name)



##################  WHATEVER YOU WANT BELOW UNTIL LINE 37 ##################

# check the contents
print(df.head(2), '\n')

# make a change (or changes) to your df
# in the case just swap 'Carrot' for 'Orange' in the 'Product' column
df.loc[df['Product'] == 'Carrot', 'Product'] = 'Orange'

# check the contents after the change
print(df.head(2), '\n')

# as long as you have imported from the top two lines and read the file
# and not called ExcelWriter before this point all the other lines above
# are up to you.

##################  WHATEVER YOU NEED ABOVE AFTER LINE 15 ##################



# from this point on try...
book = load_workbook(filename_in)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename_out, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)

writer.save()
```

In the resulting file (in the example code above we used `filename_out = 'regionsalesslicerUpdated.xlsx'`), the slicers still work.

**Example:**

Shows 'Orange'.  Let's refresh the data...

[image]

---

Slicer/filter shows 'Orange'...

[image]

Exporting from pandas to Excel has not deleted any of the sheets etc...

[image]

We have successfully overwritten a dataframe to an existing sheet in Excel.

Comment: When I tried this it overwrites the filename_out with only the sheet from filename_in

Comment: For which file?  If you haven't tried the above code with the test file do so.  Download the test file and use the code above as is.  See what that produces.

Comment: I've realized the problem, it is not just a slicer it is a slicer EXTENTION which apparently is not supported. Would you know a work around for a slicer EXTENTION?

Comment: No according to [Charlie's comment from Oct 2020 on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/openpyxl-users/c/TKnnFMISB0c)

Comment: Thanks for finding that, I tried looking for that and was unable to find anything like that when I searched. Since I am pretty new to Python what did you google to get that answer?

Comment: Just "excel slicer extension openpyxl".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this if you are writing directly to the sheet unless you would like to pay for xlwings. A better (and easier to manage) solution is to change the way you are collecting your data from excel - Also, it won't break any dashboards or slicers you have. It will require some adjustments to your overall data pipeline and how you process it. Again, a one time thing that will pay dividends in the future.

Instead of writing directly to a sheet in the file, you can write to a separate file altogether.

`df.to_excel(writer_path_to_seperate_sheet, sheet_name, index=False)`

From excel you can now import this file (and every other file that you may write to the folder in the future) via power query.

[image: power_query_how_to]

Select either the file with your data, or preferably, the folder which will contain your file and all future files. Click combine and transform.

[image: power_query_combine_transform]

Once you complete this step, you can adjust your data set to your liking and load it. It will be a table by default (perfect for pivot tables and anything else). When new files are written to the folder, you simply click refresh on the table data set and wala. All slicers and other dashboard/pivots are left unaffected.